# What's the equivalent bs-config.js (Browsersync) of this command?

Tags: browser-sync

Browsersync is working fine with a PHP/Symfony 3 project with the following command:

```
browser-sync start --proxy http://localhost:8000 --files "web/css/**/*.css"
```

The browser will open at http://localhost:3000 and if I change something in `web/css` I can see the updated stylesheets without a full page reload. So far so good.

However it doesn't work with the following `bs-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    "files": [
        "web/css/**/*.css"
    ],
    "server": false,
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
};
```

And the command:

```
browser-sync start
```

Browser will not load, changes aren't detected and reloading doesn't work. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

**1º Create "bs-config.js" with:** browser-sync init

**2º Open file and edit like this:**

```
module.exports = {
"ui": {
    "port": 3001,
    "weinre": {
        "port": 8080
    }
},
"files": "web/css/**/*.css",
"watchOptions": {},
"server": false,
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
"port": 3000,
"middleware": false,
"serveStatic": [],
"ghostMode": {
    "clicks": true,
    "scroll": true,
    "forms": {
        "submit": true,
        "inputs": true,
        "toggles": true
    }
},
"logLevel": "info",
"logPrefix": "BS",
"logConnections": false,
"logFileChanges": true,
"logSnippet": true,
"rewriteRules": [],
"open": "local",
"browser": "default",
"cors": false,
"xip": false,
"hostnameSuffix": false,
"reloadOnRestart": false,
"notify": true,
"scrollProportionally": true,
"scrollThrottle": 0,
"scrollRestoreTechnique": "window.name",
"scrollElements": [],
"scrollElementMapping": [],
"reloadDelay": 0,
"reloadDebounce": 0,
"reloadThrottle": 0,
"plugins": [],
"injectChanges": true,
"startPath": null,
"minify": true,
"host": null,
"localOnly": false,
"codeSync": true,
"timestamps": true,
"clientEvents": [
    "scroll",
    "scroll:element",
    "input:text",
    "input:toggles",
    "form:submit",
    "form:reset",
    "click"
],
"socket": {
    "socketIoOptions": {
        "log": false
    },
    "socketIoClientConfig": {
        "reconnectionAttempts": 50
    },
    "path": "/browser-sync/socket.io",
    "clientPath": "/browser-sync",
    "namespace": "/browser-sync",
    "clients": {
        "heartbeatTimeout": 5000
    }
},
"tagNames": {
    "less": "link",
    "scss": "link",
    "css": "link",
    "jpg": "img",
    "jpeg": "img",
    "png": "img",
    "svg": "img",
    "gif": "img",
    "js": "script"
}};
```

**3º Run the server:** php -S localhost:8000

**4º Start BrowserSync:** browser-sync start --config bs-config.js